# How to store values using onchange in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, odoo-10

If I save the amount_total value changes to prior position because it is readonly. i want that field to be readonly.

```
discount = fields.Selection([('fixed', 'fixed Price'), ('percentage', 'Percentage')], string="Discount")
amount = fields.Float("Amount")
total = fields.Float("Discounted Amount", store=True, compute='discount_amount')
amount_total = fields.Monetary(string='Total', store=True,readonly=True, compute='_amount_all')




    @api.onchange('total')
def totalamount(self):
    if self.total:
        self.amount_total -= self.total
```

How to deal with this

Comment: You don't need to use onchange, just edit your function `discount_amount`

Comment: computed fields are automatically checked and recomputed, they do not need an onchange.You need to change `amount_total` inside `_amount_all` method.

Comment: add in your function `discount_amount`the res of amount_total field  `record.amount_total = - rocord.total`

Comment: Your field will be like `amount_total  = fields.Float("Total", store=True, compute='discount_amount')`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing on change function you can do like the following

```
@api.depends('total')
def _amount_all(self):
    if self.total:
       total_amount = self.amount_total - self.total
    self.update({
           'amount_total': total_amount
        })
```

Comment: is this a button action or a compute function?@sfx

Comment: This is a compute function Mr. Navi